# How to store and fetch json data into room in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to Insert JSON data into the room library and fetch the same JSON data as I stored.
My JSON look like

```
{
    "Category_Name": [
        "Combo and Thali",
        "Festival combo snack and list"
    ],
    "Alldishitems": [
        [
            {
                "DishId": "1",
                "Subcategory": "Combo",
                "DishName": "Rajma Masala Combo",
                "DishPrice": "136",
                "DishNewPrice": "136",
                "Dishdescription": ""
            },
            {
                "DishId": "2",
                "Subcategory": "Combo",
                "DishName": "Lassi with Aloo Paratha",
                "DishPrice": "100",
                "DishNewPrice": "100",
                "Dishdescription": ""
            },
            {
                "DishId": "3",
                "Subcategory": "Thali",
                "DishName": "Chinise thali",
                "DishPrice": "100",
                "DishNewPrice": "100",
                "Dishdescription": ""
            },
            {
                "DishId": "4",
                "Subcategory": "Thali",
                "DishName": "Rajasthani Thali",
                "DishPrice": "100",
                "DishNewPrice": "100",
                "Dishdescription": ""
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "DishId": "5",
                "Subcategory": "snack",
                "DishName": "rajma rice",
                "DishPrice": "100",
                "DishNewPrice": "100",
                "Dishdescription": ""
            }
        ]

    ]
}
```

I want to fetch data like following

```
List<String> category
List<List<MenulistMode>> menulistmodel
```

How can I do this? please, somebody, help me

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027487/insert-json-data-using-room-library

Comment: search for Retrofit2 and realm database, you can find your solution .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert JSON data using Room Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027487/insert-json-data-using-room-library)

Comment: I want to store data using ViewModel but getting error